# Why is /arch/x86/boot/header.S in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, operating-system

Why is this file written in assembly while it could simply use an easier language like c? and why hasn't anyone still attempted to rewrite it in c?

Comment: What makes you believe C is easier than assembly? I think it's the exactly opposite way. Besides that one of the first lines is directive `.code16` ... I think the modern C compilers either don't produce 16b code any more at all, or with heavy limitations. Another early instruction is `sti` ... now this is completely off limits in C. Maybe you can attempt that to realize how "easy" it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a boot-related code and it's architecture dependent. Some of bootloader code constructs (say, stack-related) might not be representable in C without breaking its major conventions. At the same time, usage of such constructs is typically unavoidable in the boot process.

Well, there is a school of thought that you *could* write a boot-related code in C but anyway you would still have to use much inline-assembly in it to access very low-level features in your code.

Also, a typical bootloader has to deal with a handful of *limitations*.
One of the limitations (at least, for `x86`) is that when the machine is powered on, the processor starts running in 16 bit [real mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode). Less than 1 MB of RAM is available for use (boot facilities need to be small enough to fit in), no virtual memory mechanism is avaiable and, in general, memory addressing mode is quite restricted. When BIOS POST program reads the boot sector from either boot device (say, HDD), the loaded program has to read more facilities from the disk to memory and pass control to them. Obviously, as no OS is running at that point, no *OS* device drivers are available, and no standard C approach (say, using the standard IO library) is applicable. Instead, it's BIOS which provides device drivers which serve a well-defined set of interrupts (in example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H ) to access data on different boot drives. So, roughly, the boot manager *has to be written* in assembly to use a very specific set of BIOS features in real mode.

All in all, taking all the points into account (code size, 16 bit real mode limitations, the need to use BIOS-specific features and code constructs not representable in C), the answer is that writing the whole code in assembly would be the most efficient and *unambiguous* way rather than extending C to handle non-standard constructs or use badly-readable mixture of C and inline-assembly code.

P.S. If you're interested in a more detailed description of bootloader internals, it would be useful to refer to a very eloquent example of FreeBSD bootstrapping and kernel initialisation: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/arch-handbook/boot-overview.html